# Is it possible to replicate/cluster two different databases

Tags: sql-server, cluster, mysql-replication

I would like to know if it's possible to replicate or cluster a table between mssql and mysql.

That could be usefull during a migration process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication between SQL Server and MySQL is possible, although is not supported by MS. Eg. [How do I... Set up replication between Microsoft SQL Server 2000 and MySQL](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=112)

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be possible.

If it is it will likely be by dumping the database; parsing it then restoring it to another database. Which will only happen if your tables are really really simple, even then....

It wouldn't ever be supported by vendor so when you hit issues you will be all alone.

Your best hope is to write a custom program that connects to both databases and replicates meaningful data from one to the other; but this will be really case specific and unlikely to get you the real time "cluster" you might need.

So in short it will come down to your data but the general answer is "no".